# How to configure spring cloud function to accept only HTTP POST method

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I am a new learner to spring-cloud-function framework.
I am trying to build a simple cloud function using spring-cloud-function framework and deploy in GCP cloud function. I am able to deploy it and test it out.
However, it is accepting all the HTTP method type like GET, POST, PUT etc.

I want to restrict my cloud function to accept only POST method (Something like @PostMapping). Can anyone guide me on how to achieve it.

I am unable to find out on how to restrict cloud function calling to any specific HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official Spring Cloud Function documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_crud_rest_with_spring_cloud_function) for CRUD REST:

> By now it should be clear that functions are exported as REST endpoints and can be invoked using various HTTP methods. In other words a single function could be triggered via GET, POST, PUT etc.
>
> However, it is not always desirable and certainly does not fit the CRUD concept. And while SCF does not support and has no intention of supporting all the features of Spring web stack, the framework does provide support for CRUD mappings where a single function could be mapped to a particular HTTP method(s). It is done via `spring.cloud.function.http.<method-name>` property.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> spring.cloud.function.http.GET=uppercase;reverse;foo|bar
> spring.cloud.function.http.POST=reverse
> spring.cloud.function.http.DELETE=deleteById
> ```
>
> As you can see, here we’re mapping functions to various HTTP methods using the same rules as `spring.cloud.function.definition` property where “;” allows us to define several functions and “|” signifies function composition.